# How to restore MBR of Windows (10) if I have a clone of the disk? (restore the MBR only)

Tags: windows-10, backup, mbr, restore, bcd

All the search results explain how to attempt to fix a broken boot record without a backup.

I have a backup. I have a clone of the whole physical disk (not just the partition). Due to reasons, I don't want to restore the whole disk clone, I just want to fix the MBR by using this clone. Or am I wrong to assume using a backup is the best way to fix this?

But I don't remember/know much about how this works. I plugged both the broken disk and the clone disk in my spare windows laptop as external storage. Now what? :)

---

The boot message says something like "MBR failed, boot from *something else*?". I tried to "Rebuild MBR" with Easeus and it claied success but it didn't work.

Comment: Can windows10 even install on MBR disk?? I would think it would be GPT, and I would think using windows install media (rather than asus tools) would be the thing. Someone with windows knowledge will hopefully be along to help.

Comment: This is a special case machine that was MBR, got upgraded from 7 to 10, and due to some lab conditions hasn't been updated for a couple years :) But yes, you can install windows 10 with legacy MBR (at least you def could at the time and prolly still can) https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-setup-installing-using-the-mbr-or-gpt-partition-style?view=windows-11 And mine in this case is MBR.

Comment: You can do this in Linux - # dd if=my.mbr of=/dev/sdX bs=446 count=1 (per https://linuxconfig.org/linux-backup-restore-destroy-and-install-mbr-master-boot-record )

Comment: Macrium Reflect and similar imaging software have a choice to just fix boot issues.

Comment: Is the MBR partition deleted or corrupt?

Comment: Assuming that's the case, davidgo's advice is valid however you would use your disk image/clone as the (input file) `if=` and your hard disk as the `of=` and last I remember `bs=512`. However I still think throwing some window's MBR tools at it to rebuild will be more robust and correct for any environmental changes.

Comment: If all you need is the vanilla boot code from Microsoft, just use `bootsect`. (By the way, Windows makes use of the `active` flag, so make sure you mark the correct partition as `active` as well.)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone who commented. To answer my question, there isn't an easy standard procedure to restore mbr/gpt by extracting it from a clone.
Some approaches, recommend to be tried in order:

- the mbr (or gpt) should be recoverable via the builtin recovery tools of your os. If those are missing, either somehow boot or recover them from a clone or external recovery drive, or use another windows/cmd with `bootsect`, or use tools like Macrium reflect that have repair wizards.
- you should also be able to recover from a clone. I don't know too much about the particularities of what's in and around the mbr/gpt sectors (of windows), you might need to make sure your clone has the same hardware ids, and it might get tricky to figure out what sectors to recover. Didn't have a windows solution for it, but check out davidgo and mitts in the comments to my question for doing it via linux. My linux usb stick shit the bed when met with the new (old) hardware of this pc so I gave up.
- So in my case, I tried recovering via macrium & a couple other programs, & also `bootsect` from my other windows laptop, and they either didn't change a thing despite "succeeding", or it got me a couple different versions of mbr boot failure/error messages. So not having patience for this kind of fuckery any more I: backed up my broken C disk to save all the up to date files, then I restored the whole damn clone sector by sector to the disk, which booted successfully , and then I recovered all the latest files I'd just backed up (including program files because it's a clone). This is a stupid solution that takes very long and a lot of storage space.

And mind you I know computer science, but theory != windows fuckery in practice. Guess I need a degree in the world of recovery fuckery, and another in stoic zen master patience for infuriating OS bs. ✌

Comment: word. i hear you.